# How to hide this element using CSS or JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following element:

```
<a href="http://somelink" title="Open the library that contains this result" class="ms-calloutLink ms-uppercase" id="some_random_id" clicktype="ActionViewLibrary">View Library</a>
```

I tried to hide/remove it using the CSS code below but it didn't work. I want to hide/remove this.

```
.ms-calloutLink ms-uppercase [text='Open the library that contains this result']
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide this specific elment and not an other? I mean is this following user interaction or any other specific case? You said, you can use ID because ID is random, so you have to improve your question to let us know what you are expecting exactly. Cannot you use class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //ID selector
    $("#some_random_id").hide();

    //Attribute selector
    $('a[title="Open the library that contains this result"]').hide();
});
```

OR using css

```
#some_random_id
{
   display:none;
}
```

### EDIT

CSS

```
.ms-calloutLink.ms-uppercase[title='Open the library that contains this result']
{
   display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UR66D/1/)

Comment: Can't us this because the ID is random and changes everytime.

Comment: @FrankMartin, You can use attribute selector `$('a[title="Open the library that contains this result"]').hide();`

Comment: @FrankMartin, You can use ` .ms-calloutLink.ms-uppercase[title='Open the library that contains this result']
    {
       display:none;
    }` See Demo http://jsfiddle.net/UR66D/1/

Comment: @Satpal i guess OP will say he cannot use it because he doesn't know what will be the title etc... In fact, question is unclear

Comment: @A.Wolff, If OP will say that then definitely I totally agree with you

Comment: at least you have fixed CSS +1

Answer (score 1):

You can hide using both css and jQuery.

*Using css*

```
.ms-calloutLink
{
   display:none;
}
```

*Using jQuery, you can use id selector, if you want to hide on page load then put the hiding code in document.ready event handler*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_random_id').hide();
});
```

If you want to hide on some event, like on some button click

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function(){
    $('#some_random_id').hide();
});
```

Edit, based on comments, if id of an element is dynamic you can use class selector.

```
$('.ms-calloutLink.ms-uppercase').hide();
```

Comment: i guess you mean: `#some_random_id` but then if it is randomized, how will you target it? I'm not sure thought what random means here

Comment: The id is random and changes everytime so can't use this code.

Comment: You can use class selector, instead of id selector.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding it using css is your best bet

```
a.ms-calloutLink.ms-uppercase[title='Open the library that contains this result'] {
   display:none;
}
```

Alternately, you can add an inline style if you have access to the html

```
<a href="http://somelink" style="display:none;" title="Open the library that contains this result" class="ms-calloutLink ms-uppercase" id="some_random_id" clicktype="ActionViewLibrary" >View Library</a>
```

To use jQuery to hide the element, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.ms-calloutLink.ms-uppercase[title*="Open the library]"').hide();
});
```

The jQuery function will find all anchor tags with the classes 'ms-calloutLink' and 'ms-uppercase' that also have a title that contains the words "Open the library".

I'm assuming here that you won't have multiple anchor tags with this same title/class combinations.  If you do, please update your question and I will update my response :).

Happy Coding!